# Changing the input voltage to a step-up transformer, will this alter the output amps?

Tags: transformer

I am working on a project using a transformer, input 120vac 60hz and output of 2000v 50ma. My question is this, if I reduce the input power what should I expect to see on the output in regards to the amps?  In the end I would like to alter the output amperage from the established standard and down to a much lower value.  Thanks in advance for any constructive input.

Comment: How do you propose to reduce the input power while maintaining the output voltage? You could reduce the source voltage, but given the same transformer you will get a lower output voltage. And you don't say you want that. Your real problem appears to be your perception that you want to reduce the output current compliance. But I don't know why. Do you want to make it "safer" in some way? Is this about your own confusion that you have load that uses less current than 50 mA at 2 kV? What's your thinking here??

Comment: It is an artistic application and the final output voltage and amperage variance will produce different results.  I have applied different transformers into the project and I know what the end results of each provides.  I was planning to introduce a variable input power via a regulated power source; tapped variac unit.  Safety is always an issue with this range of electrical potential but no my desires are for an artistic end result.  Thanks for your input and considerations!

Comment: The supply can control the output voltage, or the output current, but not both. The load matters, though the load can have a rather complex relationship to the voltage. (Gas discharge requires at least 2D spatial and 1D time of PDE coupled to at least 6D ODE, without radiation transport and atomic interactions. Simplified, can uses global rate equations that assume spatially averaged densities for the charged particles and neutral atoms and molecules, but still needs to deal with excited and metastable states.) So I just won't worry anymore. You have answers. I just wondered, is all.

Answer (score 0):

The output amperage is dependent on the load, but current and voltage is inversely proportional, and output voltage is a multiple of the input. Maximum output current will be dependent on the physical properties of the coils in the transformer coil, typically.

Answer (score 0):

- Your transformer will behave as a sinusoidal *voltage* source. That means the output voltage should remain fairly constant over an output current range, 0 to 50 mA in your case.
- The current drawn will depend on the load. For a resistive load the current will be given by Ohm's law, \$ I = \frac {V}{R} \$.
- If you reduce the input voltage the output voltage will decrease proportionately. For a resistive load the current will reduce in proportion to the reduction in voltage.
- You might think that you can draw more current at a lower voltage but this may not be the case as the secondary winding will be rated for a certain current due to the wire gauge.

> My question is this, if I reduce the input power what should I expect to see on the output in regards to the amps?

- If you reduce the input *voltage* you will reduce the output voltage.
- Power out of the transformer will be given by \$ P_{OUT} = V_{OUT}I_{OUT} \$.
- Therefore, if you decrease the input *voltage* you will, with a resistive load, decrease the input power because you are reducing the load power.
- Power in will be a bit higher due to losses in the transformer.

Comment: Your input is most welcome and appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> My question is this, if I reduce the input power what should I expect to see on the output in regards to the amps?

You can't change the input power, from the input side. You *can* change the input voltage. However, it's the secondary loading, how much current it draws from the secondary voltage, that gets reflected back to the primary side, scaled by the turn ratio, to define how much current the primary draws, and therefore how much power the transformer takes.

Reducing input voltage will reduce output voltage. For a constant secondary load, that will reduce secondary current and therefore primary current.

Comment: Which is exactly what I want it to do.  I had the thought and had to say it out loud to get it out of my head.  Thanks for your input!